How to code a meta score from a formula using columns of scores in python
I have a dataframe of multiple columns of scores in python. Using each score I am trying to calculate a meta score.
I am trying to calculate the meta score following this formula:

(it comes from this paper but it does not have code available: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-13848-1).
However, I don't have a maths background so I am unsure if I am coding the formula correctly.
Right now I have:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

score_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000, 13), columns=[f'SCORE{i}' for i in range(1, 14)])

# Elastic-net regression coefficients (need to optimize settings)
elastic_net_coefficients = np.array([0.12, 0.08, 0.15, 0.10, 0.07, 0.13, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.05, 0.06, 0.04, 0.10])

standardized_score_data = (score_data - score_data.mean()) / score_data.std()

meta_score = standardized_score_data.values.dot(elastic_net_coefficients)

score_data['metaSCORE'] = meta_score

Am I along the right lines with how to code this, is the dot product function what I am looking for? Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

Can you explain your formula?What are Xij , coefficients inside the parantesis, .. ?
